# How to setup an unobstrusive validation group?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I've created a MVC 4, validation attribute that will compare 2 fields, that represent a year range, to validate that the end year is not before the start year.

I've created the following JS:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'yearrange', ['startyear', 'endyear'], function (options) {
            options.rules['yearrange'] = options.params;
            options.messages['yearrange'] = options.message;        
        }
    );

jQuery.validator.addMethod(
            'yearrange', function (value, element, params) {

                var startYearElementName = params.startyear;
                var endYearElementName = params.endyear;

                var startYear = $('#' + startYearElementName).val();
                var endYear = $('#' + endYearElementName).val();

                if (startYear == '' || endYear == '') {
                    return true;
                }

                return (+startYear <= +endYear);

            }, '');
```

I'm applying the validation attribute to both properties in my ViewModel:

```
[YearRange("StartYear", "EndYear", "yearRangeInvalid")]
public int StartYear { get; set; }

[YearRange("StartYear", "EndYear", "yearRangeInvalid")]
public int EndYear { get; set; }
```

I don't want to use a summary validation message.

Can I use validation groups to trigger the re-validation of both fields when one is changed?

And can it be configured in the adapters.add callback above?

I unsuccessfully tried something like:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'yearrange', ['startyear', 'endyear'], function (options) {
            options.rules['yearrange'] = options.params;
            options.messages['yearrange'] = options.message;

            jQuery.validator.groups[options.params.startyear] = "yearrange";
            jQuery.validator.groups[options.params.endyear] = "yearrange";

        }
    );
```